# How to allow for more time to respond to interaction in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command which takes a while to get everything ready and it wont work because the interaction times out before it can do anything, I have tried using interaction.deferReply() but that just came up with a undefined error.

Comment: Use `interaction.deferReply()`. Any interaction will timeout after 15 minutes. If you're unable to provide a response within that time frame then that's an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interaction.deferReply()` shows the user "`bot name` is thinking...". Make sure that when you're ready to respond, you run `interaction.editReply("your response")`